# How do I convert the number of rows returned into a percentage?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the query

```
Select * From [July] Where [UserName] = 'Belle'
```

Which returns 55 rows but this could change depending of the month.

I want to query the percentage of each month based on the size of the total table.

Example: This month we have 55 'Belle' in the table and 183 total rows in the table, so it will be 30%.

How can I query that 30%?

```
Table1
Username | Percentage             
Belle    |  30%       
Foo      |  20%
```

I'd also like to convert the 30% into the total size taken up by the rows, in kilobytes, but that is a different question.

Comment: _"add another row Inside my C# table"_ what kind of table are you talking about? Instead of having tables like `July` or storing aggregates values like `30%` you should calculate these values from the data and store the month in a `datetime` or `date` column.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Technically i have table call  table1 Inside my sql server the size is 2GB
on my XAML Project i have a table , that show all the duplicate username for example belle  from table1, depending of the month sometime we can 55 duplicate or 5 duplicate, so i just want know how to turn those duplicate into a percentage for example 55 row take about 25mb Inside table1 which is about 30% of table1 space 
is that any clear or not ?

Comment: @Adou you're question isn't very clear but I've attempted to answer it. If I've misunderstood can you edit your question to be a little clearer?

Comment: You mean 1 row takes approx 500kb ?? Also, do you want a C# solution or a SQL solution ? Are changes to be made in the database or in the app ? Please change your question tags accordingly. Finally, please make shorter sentences : it will make it **a lot** clearer.

Comment: I want a C# Solution  @Rafalon 
@ Captainjamie thanks for the answer , that didn't do the trick  but will try figure it out  
i'm new to this Stackoverflow , perhaps i will like to add some picture maybe this will make it clear but i do not know how to

Comment: @Adou I said writing shorter sentences will help making it clearer. Explain what you want to achieve, then what you tried, then what results you got and how it differs from what you wanted.

Comment: @Adou: *"55 row take about 25mb Inside table1 which is about 30% of table1 space"* - I don't see how you're even getting those numbers.  Or how disk space even matters in these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is quite easy:

```
DECLARE @total INT;

SELECT @total = COUNT(*) FROM <TableName>;

WITH [GroupedTable] AS (
    SELECT
       [Name] = <ColumnName>,
       [Count] = SUM(1)
    FROM
       <TableName>
    GROUP BY
       <ColumnName>
)
SELECT
    [Value] = [Name],
    [Percentage] = CAST([Count] AS decimal(19,10)) / @total * 100
FROM 
    [GroupedTable]
ORDER BY
    [Percentage] DESC
```

the 'with' just groups the table by the column, and counts the number of occurrences of that value. The second select just projects this data as a percentage. To get the percentage we just need to count up the total number of rows, which is the what the @total bit does. Hope this helps.

Comment: this Code work fine,i now want 2 know how many column return & the percentage of it(i have 2 cut code to long
`  string request = "SELECT Golf.* " + (User_name!=""?", oRDINAL_POSITION":"") + " FROM table1 golf"
                + (user_name!=""?" LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns ON (golf.name_field=information_schema.columns.COLUMN_NAME AND information_schema.columns.table_name='LOADING_" + user_name + "')":")
                 + " WHERE User_id=" + user_id.ToString()
                 + " ORDER BY field_name" + (ascending == true ? "" : " DESC");

            return xmlDoc;
        }`

Comment: @Adou No idea what you're asking but you'd better hope someone doesn't pick the username: 'DROP TABLE Golf; --